# Set values to html tag from angularjs controller not working

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I want to show the user profile values in HTML via an AngularJs controller, but it isn't showing in the html `<p>` where I bind them.
[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rawat/k3phygpz/533/)

**AngularJs App:**

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.service('UserService', function () {
    var userDetails = [{
            id : 27,
            first_name : 'Addy',
            last_name : 'Villiams',
            gender : 1,
            email : 'addy@villiams.com',
            creation_date : '2015-09-23 10:53:19.423',
            age : 25,
            profile_pic : 'avatar.get?uid=27'
    }];

    this.get = function () {
        return userDetails;
    }
});


app.controller('UserController', function ($scope, UserService) {

    $scope.userinfo = UserService.get();

});
```

**HTML:**

```
<div ng-controller="UserController">
    <p>{{userinfo.id}}</p>
    <p>{{userinfo.first_name}}</p>
</div>
```

Comment: You are returning an array from your service `var userDetails = [{` try returning just the straight object.... [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/k3phygpz/534/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The returned object from service is an **array** with one object.

```
$scope.userinfo = UserService.get()[0]; // Get the first element from array
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/k3phygpz/535/)

Or change the service to return an Object instead of array.

```
var userDetails = {
    id: 27,
    first_name: 'Addy',
    last_name: 'Villiams',
    gender: 1,
    email: 'addy@villiams.com',
    creation_date: '2015-09-23 10:53:19.423',
    age: 25,
    profile_pic: 'avatar.get?uid=27'
};
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/k3phygpz/536/)

Comment: @PraveenRawat Welcome! :)

Answer (score 1):

So your service UserService.get() returns array of objects so userinfo.id and userinfo.first_name are undefined. You can resolve it returning just object or using on view 
`userinfo[0].id` and 
`userinfo[0].first_name`. Please check fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/rawat/k3phygpz/533/

Answer (score 1):

You initialized user object in array. You can remove the square brackets [] from user initialization:

```
var userDetails = {
    id: 27,
    first_name: 'Addy',
    last_name: 'Villiams',
    gender: 1,
    email: 'addy@villiams.com',
    creation_date: '2015-09-23 10:53:19.423',
    age: 25,
    profile_pic: 'avatar.get?uid=27'
};
```

or use

```
$scope.userinfo = UserService.get()[0];
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove the [] braces - you should return an object not an array:

```
var userDetails = {
    id: 27,
    first_name: 'Addy',
    last_name: 'Villiams',
    gender: 1,
    email: 'addy@villiams.com',
    creation_date: '2015-09-23 10:53:19.423',
    age: 25,
    profile_pic: 'avatar.get?uid=27'
};
```